# Convert Java Object to TSV in java

Tags: java

I generate a report where I read data from postgresql and then populate a Java object
Below is kind of sample skeleton where I want to show there are many collection object within Main object i.e ReportMessageStructure

```
public class ReportMessageStructure {
    
       
    protected MessageHeader messageHeader;
    
    protected MessageDuration messageDuration;
    
    protected ObjectA sampleListA;
    
    protected ObjectB sampleListB;
    
    protected ObjectC smapleListC;

   }
```

Now My requirement is to write data into TSV file . Could you please suggest me best way to do this. I know I can use JAXB if I had to convert into XML. However need way to convert into TSV. Any tips/suggestion would be great help.

Max size the data will produce would be around 700MB from object to TSV

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. You should try something yourself before asking a question.

Comment: The Java ecosystem offers several good [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)/[TSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values) file writing/reading libraries. I suggest you take a look at each, to get a sense of how they work. Then [search Stack Overflow](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+CSV+TSV+tab-delimited&t=osx&ia=web) for Questions on those libraries, to learn a bit more. If, after that research, you have specific technical questions, *then* post here.

Comment: thanks for review @Code-Apprentice.  I should have added more tried approach also. like I added above there is JAXB which takes are XML  to Java object and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`CSVPrinter`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVPrinter.html) from [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/index.html) library with [`CSVFormat`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html) equal to `TDF`.

```java
try (CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(new FileWriter("csv.txt"), CSVFormat.TDF)) {
     printer.printRecord("id", "userName", "firstName", "lastName", "birthday");
     printer.printRecord(1, "john73", "John", "Doe", LocalDate.of(1973, 9, 15));
     printer.println();
     printer.printRecord(2, "mary", "Mary", "Meyer", LocalDate.of(1985, 3, 29));
 } catch (IOException ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: I like this approach thanks a lot Alex. I like this approach as this has way to write iterable also in one go. I will try this out and will post here my result. thanks